# SSIS Package not executed by SQL Server Agent using password or xml config or table config

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS package that takes data from a MySQL database and puts it in to a SQL Server table. The connection to MySQL is ADO.net. The package runs fine in BIDS.

I would like to deploy the package to be run as a Job on SQL Server 2008. The MySQL connection requires sensitive data to be either stored within the package or held in some external configuration source. If it is stored within the package it will either by encrypted with a key specific to my windows user profile or must be protected via a password.

I have tried three methods of setting up a SQL Server Agent job to execute this pacakge,  and all fail:

**Using a Password**

I set the ProtectionLevel of the package to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and supply a password for the package. I then save a copy of the package to the msdb. I can then connect to SSIS and run the package, at which point I am prompted for a password.

When I try to schedule this as a job in SQL Server I am prompted to enter the password by clicking on the Configurations tab of the Job Step Properties and I can see that the /DECRYPT switch has been added to the Command Line tab. The Run As property is set to the SQL Server Agent Service Account, which is mapped to a database login that has sysadmin server role. When I attempt to start this job I get the following error:

```
Executed as user: DOMAIN\UserROLE. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.5500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  12:31:30  Error: 2012-07-03 12:31:31.20     Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: Get Data Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire connection "DATA_SOURCE". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE
```

It seems that using this method the package password itself is not stored anywhere for the job to access it.

**Using an XML configuration file**

I then created a copy of the package and set the ProtectionLevel to DontSaveSensitive and I set up a package configuration to store the MySQL credentials in an XML file. I then save this to the msdb and then when I run the package from 
Integration Services I can provide a path to the config file, and all is well. However, once again when I set up a job for the package I point to a configuration file on the server but the job fails with the same error. I am wondering whether this is because the SQL Server Agent does not have an associated windows account that would allow it to read from the XML file stored in the file system.

**Using a SQL Server table configuration**

This time I created a copy of the package and set the ProtectionLevel to ServerStorage. I then created a [SSIS Configurations] table in the target SQL Server database. I modified the entries in this table to contain the password for the MySQL data source. Again, the package runs successfully from Integration Services, but fails with the same error as previously when run from a job. I have checked that the SQL Server Agent is able to read from the [SSIS Configurations] table ok - I set up a standalone job to test this.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what else I should do here?

I am thinking of giving up on SQL Server Agent Jobs for this and going back to having the package scheduled simply by the windows scheduler but thought before throwing in the towel I would try here first.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the method of encrypting the password by setting `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword` as you discribed above and don't see anything you do wrong. Remember to use option `keep protection level of the original package` when importing the package with integration services, but it looks like you're doing that, too.

Try setting the role `SQLAgentOperatorRole` to your SQL Server Agent Service Account, you didn't mention that and i am not sure if you did. This could possibly solve your permission problems. (liked to answer by commenting this, but i lack of permissions here, too :)

Comment: Thanks stb. I have tried your suggestion regarding the SQLAgentOperatorRole but it does not seem to have had the desired effect. I am already importing my package keepin the protection level of original package.

Comment: I found a 'general troubleshooting' video concerning your problem. Maybe this helps: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff686900.aspx

Comment: Thanks again @stb I have actually seen that video and it misses the detail of the critical bits that I need to see! I gave MS some feedback to that effect. I think I'll give up on this and just schedule my package using the Windows scheduler. Appreciate your time anyhow.